# TTL of Dynamic Private IP Address for Azure VMs?

Tags: azure-virtual-machine

What's the time to live for private IPs that are dynamic and assigned to NICs for Azure based VMs?

Comment: Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the description of the dynamic IP address [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-network-interface-addresses#dynamic):

> Once assigned, dynamic IP addresses are only released if a network
> interface is deleted, assigned to a different subnet within the same
> virtual network, or the allocation method is changed to static, and a
> different IP address is specified. By default, Azure assigns the
> previous dynamically assigned address as the static address when you
> change the allocation method from dynamic to static.

So it means if you do not delete or change the configuration of the network interface of the VM, then the dynamic IP address will work as the static IP address.